# use of undeclared type 'CPTMutableAxisLabelSet'

Tags: swift, graph, core-plot

I am able to install the core plot 2.2 with the help of pod. I wanted to have custom labels on the x-axis using swift. for that i have written following code

```
let axisArray = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tues", "Weds", "Thurs", "Fri", "Sat"]
            let customLabel: CPTMutableAxisLabelSet = []
            let tickLocation: NSArray = [3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21]
            var labelLocation: Int = -1
            for var number in tickLocation {
                labelLocation += 1
                let newLabel = CPTAxisLabel.init(text: axisArray[labelLocation], textStyle: x.labelTextStyle)
                newLabel.tickLocation = number as! NSNumber
                newLabel.offset = x.labelOffset + x.majorTickLength
                newLabel.rotation = CGFloat(M_PI /  Double(4.0))
                customLabel.add(newLabel)
            }
            x.axisLabels = NSSet.init(array: (customLabel as AnyObject) as! [Any]) as! Set<CPTAxisLabel>
```

It gives compiler error as "use of undeclared type 'CPTMutableAxisLabelSet'". If i try to replace "CPTMutableAxisLabelSet" with "NSMutableArray" then application is crashing. Can any one help me how to create custom label in swift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's much simpler to just use Swift collections.

```
var customLabels = Set<CPTAxisLabel>()
// create the custom labels and add them to the set
x.axisLabels = customLabels
```